# What should be the reaction between lead oxide and dilute sulfuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I know for a fact that dilute $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a non-oxidizing acid which makes it a reducing agent. I also know for a fact that $\ce{PbO2}$ is a strong oxidizing agent. So, I thought Redox reaction should have occurred between them, but my teacher says that no reaction occurs between the said reactants because $\ce{PbO2}$ does not react with low concentration of acid. If it were so, why does $\ce{PbO2}$ react with dilute $\ce{HCl}$. Since, both dilute $\ce{HCl}$ and dilute H2SO4 are reducing acids of low concentrations, both should be eligible for the Redox reaction.

I have tried this on the internet but all I get are reaction balancing links .JD Lee's Concise Inorganic Chemistry has nothing about this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOur logic is wrong.

> I know for a fact that dilute $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a non-oxidizing acid...

sort of, but so far so good.

> ...**which makes** it a reducing agent.

This is where you are wrong, just because it is non-oxidizing does not make it reducing. Concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ is an oxidizer, diluting it does not make it less of an oxidizer, but limits the strength/mechanism.

A similar example is mixing [nitroglycerin and diatomaceous earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamite) doesn't make nitroglycerin less explosive, it just makes it harder for it to explode (dynamite).

Comment: So, what you mean is dilute sulfuric acid is still an oxidizing acid but its capacity has been diluted to the point that it cannot oxidize appreciably anymore.

Comment: @Lucifer - Yes.